# Ionic 3 Unique Buttons

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new in Ionic and using Ionic v3.

I have *ngFor repeater rendering a list of cards, and each card contain an image and a button under each image,
How can i make the button unique. I want only the clicked button under the image to change its name and color. the code now change all the buttons in the rendered cards.

```
<ion-card no-padding padding-bottom no-margin class="card" *ngFor="let c of cards;">

<ion-row>
  <img src={{c.Image}} />
</ion-row>

 <button clear ion-button icon-only (click)="likeButton(c)" class="like-btn">
    <ion-icon no-padding [name]="like_btn.icon_name" color="{{ like_btn.color }}" class="icon-space"></ion-icon>
</button>

</ion-card>
```

and here its the .ts

```
likeButton(c: any) {
   if(this.like_btn.icon_name === 'heart-outline') {
      this.like_btn.icon_name = 'heart';
      this.like_btn.color = 'danger';
      // Do some API job in here for real!
   }
   else {
      this.like_btn.icon_name = 'heart-outline';
      this.like_btn.color = 'black';
   }
}
```

[Array of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngSnZ.png)

Comment: You have 3 pages. Each page should have its own like button, with its own color and icon. So the color and the icon should be properties of the page, not properties of the component that displays all the pages. Otherwise, you only have one color, and one icon. Or you can have a like-button-component, and use one such component for each page.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for answering, i edited my question to make it more clear. 
can you please look it at and let me know, cause i didn't quite understand your solution.

Comment: If you want a red button on the first card and a green button on the second card, and a blue button on the third card, you need to have three different color variables, not just one. If you had 1000 cards, you would need 1000 variables. There is a direct correlation here: each card must have its own color and thus its own variable to hold that color. So instead of storing the color on `this` (i.e. the component, which is unique), you need to store it on the card itself: `<ion-icon ... [color]="c.color" ...>`. `likeButton(c: Card) {
   if(c.icon_name === 'heart-outline') { ...`.

Comment: @JBNizet.. i need a heart button, same like instagram. so each clicked button will be colored red, and gets back to black when clicked again. what i am facing here is that on the click all the buttons get colored red and not only the clicked one.

Comment: Yes, I understand that perfectly. Have you read my comments? What is unclear in it? What don't you understand? Let's say you have a class Component. And this class Component has an array of 3 Persons. Each person must have a different name. Where should the `name` property defined? On the Component object, or on the User objects? Same here. You have 3 cards, each with a color. Where should the color be defined? On the Component, or on the Card?

Comment: Can you share your current array - cards?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko i added the link of arrays in the description:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngSnZ.png

Comment: @JBNizet yes i read your comment, and i'm working on your suggestions.

Comment: @JBNizet it's working now. Unfortunately i'm unable to pick your answer yet. There's some kind of badges i need to earn.

Comment: I only posted comments, no answer. Don't worry about that. You can simply delete your question: numerous similar questions have already been asked and answered already.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead add an attribute to the card object in the array that stores whether it is 'liked' (say a boolean for example), then in your view you could iterate over the array and update the specific card when the user clicks the button:

```
<ion-card no-padding padding-bottom no-margin class="card" *ngFor="let c of cards>

<ion-row>
  <img src={{c.Image}} />
</ion-row>

 <button clear ion-button icon-only (click)="likeButton(c)" class="like-btn">
    <ion-icon no-padding [name]="c.liked ? 'heart' : 'heart-outline'" [color]="c.liked ? 'danger' : 'black'" class="icon-space"></ion-icon>
</button>

</ion-card>
```

Then in your `likeButton` method:

```
likeButton(c: any) {
   if (c.liked) {
      c.liked = false // Update the array which should also update your view  
      // Do whatever you want when a card is changed to not liked.
   } else {
      c.liked = true // Update the array which should also update your view  
      // Do whatever you want when a card is changed to liked.
   }
}
```